# How do I open file list outputted from find command?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I have a working find query `find . -type f | gshuf -n2`  which returns two lines of files. I know I can open files in text edit through `open -a TextEdit ./text.txt` but how would I put these together so Textedit opens them after finding instead of me manually copying and pasting?

I tried variations like

```
open -a TextEdit find . -type f | gshuf -n2
open -a TextEdit (find . -type f | gshuf -n2)
```

etc

Can this be done in one command or if not what's the best way?

Comment: Try `xargs` if that's available on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close with your second attempt. To substitute the output of a command into a command line, you use `$( command )`.

```
open -a TextEdit $(find . -type f | gshuf -n2)
```

However, this won't work properly if any of the filenames have spaces in their names, because each word will be treated as a separate filename. This will work better:

```
find . -type f | gshuf -n2 | while read filename; do
    open -a TextEdit "$filename"
done
```

The double quotes prevent the name from being split up.